# How To deploy asp.net core web api project with react(standalone) in visual studio 2022

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp.net-core-webapi, visual-studio-2022

I just follow https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/main/docs/javascript/tutorial-asp-net-core-with-react.md
to publish my project to local folder and then add new web site on iis.
but I don`t know how browse the index.html that created in wwwroot folder to work with api,
browsing result to :
No webpage was found for the web address:
http://localhost:7080/wwwroot/index.html
HTTP ERROR 404

Should two separate sites be created on iis?

Program.cs :

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

[image]

The index file:

[image]

Browse WebSite :

[image]

and the result :

[image]

And the postman for test api that was Success :

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I changed program.cs to below and it worked!

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

//app.MapControllers();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();

    // route non-api urls to index.html
    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");
});

app.Run();
```

Comment: Thank you! The tutorial of Microsoft should be updated with this info

Comment: This also fixed the deploy to Azure for me. Maybe my azure app service settings are wrong I don't know, but this works.

Comment: Yeah, This is really helpful! I think Microsoft should add this to their official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you don't need to deploy separately. Of course, you can deploy them separately if you need them.

We can see from the .csproj file what actions were done when it was released, and the project of the react front-end was placed under wwwroot, so the project under wwwroot can be deployed separately or directly from the deployed asp.net core project.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks, I test api by postman and it was success but address to site for index.html not work and has error when both project are in one website. the error is "crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated." but when add website to wwwroot it work except fetching from api

Comment: @Amir If you want get further help, it's better to provide some related error messages and pics.

Comment: @Amir Pls check the code in your `Program.cs` file, I want to know what the value in `app.MapFallbackToFile()`, in my side, it's `index.html`. And I rename it, then I reproduce your issue.

Comment: @Amir So pls check the it and can we find the html file under `wwwroot` folder. Or we can create a simple html file under `wwwroot` with the same name, then we can get the reason.

Comment: I add program.cs code, but i do not change on it after visual studio create it and has not app.MapFallbackToFile() ! I just follow the document that microsoft prepare for create asp.net core web api with react(standalone) project.

Comment: thanks for your friendly effort and guidance .due to last your comment I resolve problem by add app.UseStaticFiles();app.UseRouting();app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/index.html");
}); to my program.cs