# Deploy .Net app on Plesk with React app in subfolder

Tags: reactjs, .net, deployment, plesk

Is it possible to deploy .Net app and React app (in subfolder) on plesk hosting at the same time ? Any solutions or better ways for me to do it, thanks

[image]i have built and published my .Net app on Plesk and it works fine. I would like to create a subfolder then publish my React app in there. How can i access my React app by route or somethings else ?

Comment: Aren't you using the `UseSpa` middleware? Otherwise it'll be hard since you would have to host both your ASP.NET Core app and react app, which both run on a different port, or you'd have to move the frontend in the wwwroot folder, or use a proxy...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and there is my solution:

1. You should implement your separate React app to the Visual Studio in your current .Net project. [Follow this instruction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio). Make sure that weatherforecast is working
2. Configure your Program.cs like in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73784739/20432168). Configure setupProxy.js and set `const context = ["/",];`
3. Deploy to the Plesk. Check your set up of "nodejs" module, should be like in the picture [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDoja.png). Node Js in the Plesk must be **disabled**

Your React app will be in the wwwroot folder